# How to add GCC 7.2.0 compiler to CodeBlocks

Tags: gcc, codeblocks

I have a intention to use GCC 7.2.0 compiler in CodeBlocks for programing in Gfortran.
The link for compiler downloading is:

https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/?source=typ_redirect

Afther installing and starting the CodeBlocks i got this message:

`Cant find compiler executable in your configured search path for a MinGWNew`

Can this issue be solved?

Comment: Settings->Compilers->Toolchains->...

Answer (score 1):

Go to settings, select compiler, and them go to the toolchain executables. In there I hit the  auto detect and it found my compiler then hit ok and was able to compile and run my programs.